# install NodeJS + Express + Jade into Bootstrap 3 template

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, npm, pug

I have installed NodeJS + Express + Jade into a folder, its working and all.

Node -v = v0.10.32

npm -v = 1.4.28

Mac OS X 10.9.5

Sublime Text 2

what i want to do is into this project place a Bootstrap 3 Theme.
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/

How can i do this? i tried editing the app.js. Still no clue on how to do it im really new to all this. 
i found something that might be similar where editing the app.js with the following

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.html');
});
```

but does not work for me.

Thanks Very Much.

Comment: Install "into" Bootstrap. Think logically about that statement, please. I mean this is the nicest way possible.

Comment: haha don't be like that, its the way i found to say what i want to do. Solved it tho.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this what i did was paste the next line of code on the app.js that express generated.

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});
```

Then i unzipped bootstrap template into the public folder. This code calls to the index.html of the bootstrap template.